# To whom devi Radha rani was married?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana, radha

Do we have any scripture, which describe the earthly marriage of Radha-ji with a person, i.e. her husband?

Extra Qn: Keeping aside the leela part, would their love be considered as an affair from today's standard? (yes/no would suffice).

**Related**:

- [Why didn't Lord Krishna marry Radha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/277/1049)
- [If Radha and Krishna aren't married, why do we worship Them together, like Sita-Rama?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/925/1049)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20496/1049):

> अतीते द्वादशाब्दे तु दृष्ट्रा तां नवयौवनाम्।  सार्धं रायणावेशयेन तत्संबन्धं चकार सः॥ ३८ ।।
>   After the expiry of twelve years, finding her becoming youthful, **she was married to a trader named Rayana**

According to social standard, **yes**, it can be considered an **extra marital affair**.

> Radha's depictions vary from being an already married woman who becomes an adulterous lover of Krishna in a secondary role,[10] ... In some Hindu sub-traditions, Radha is conceptualized as a goddess who breaks social norms by leaving her marriage, and entering into a relationship with Krishna to pursue her love. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radha)