# Why didn't Krishna ever visit Vrindavan after leaving?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, brahma-vaivarta-purana, vrindavana

After leaving Vrindavan for killing Kansa in Mathura, why didn't Krishna ever go back to Vrindavan, where he was brought up, again? Why didn't he ever go to meet Sri Radha again?

Comment: This is very good question. +1, I am wondering and reading many texts but I am not able to find this "Why" because there are no records related to it. I will ask this question to my old aged friends, If I write answer based on some folk song or fair tales, is it okey?

Answer (score 18):

This is a good question because we all wonder it from time to time. How can Shri Krishna leave Vrindavan and His most beloved Radha and never meet Her again! Was this because He was a cheat (*chaliya*)? No, it's not. The reason is something different. Even in the scripture (Brahmavaivarta Purana), the same question has been asked:

> *kathaṃ jagāma mathurāṃ tyaktvā vṛndāvanaṃ vanam
>
>   kathaṃ tatyāja gopīśca rādhāṃ prāṇādhikāṃ priyām
>
>   yaśodāṃ bāndhavādīṃśca nandaṃ va nandanandanaḥ* [BVP - 4.55.15,16]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Why did He go to Mathura leaving Vrindavan? Why did He leave the gopis and Radharani who is dear to Him more than His life? And why did He leave Yasoda, Nanda, His kinsmen and His friends?

The reason is due to the effect of [a curse that Sridama had given to Radharani](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/393/38). As per that curse **Radharani had to experience one hundred years of separation from Her beloved Krishna**. God never lets any form of ego or pride (*ahmakar*) stay in His devotees. Then how could He have let any ego stay in the mind of Shri Radha, His most beloved, that She was the most special of all?:

> *darpahā darpadaḥ so'pi sarveṣāṃ sarvadaḥ sadā
>
>   babhañja rādhādarpaṃ ca sudāmnaḥ śāpakāraṇāt
>
>   prāṇādhikāyā rādhāyā anyeṣāmapi kā kathā* [BVP - 4.55.15,16,24]
>
> **Meaning**
>    He is the eternal extinguisher of pride of everyone and He broke the pride of Radha through the curse of Sudama. When He broke the pride of Radha, who is dear to Him more than His life, what to say about others?

So in course of events, Shri Radharani got the curse and got separated from Him for hundred years as Shri Krishna left Vrindavan to never return. However, nobody can say the particular reason why Krishna did what He did. He is the Lord of all and who can know His reasons when even Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva fail to do so? So the scripture says:

> *durjñeyaṃ tadabhiprāyaṃ ko vā jānāti putraka
>
>   yatprabhāvaṃ na jānanti brahmaviṣṇumaheśvarāḥ
>
>   kathaṃ jānāmi tacceṣṭāmahaṃ vatsa sumandadhīḥ* [BVP - 4.55.14,15]
>
> **Meaning**
>    His intentions are difficult to know. Who knows it son, when whose powers are even unknown to Brahma, Vishnu, and Mahesvara! So how can son a dull-witted like me know His intentions?

Nevertheless, when hundreds of years were over the effect of the curse was gone. So Shri Krishna meets Radharani again at a religious place where the residents of Vraj and the *yadavas* had gathered to perform some worships. In the Mahabharat, it happens in a place named Prabhasa, in this *Purana*  the place has been referred to as *Siddhashrama*. Thereafter the worship, Parvati says to Shri Radha:

> *śrīdāmnaḥ śāpanirmuktā śatavarṣāntare sati
>
>   kuruṣva madreṇādya kṛṣṇena saha saṃgamam*  [BVP - 4.124.51]
>
> **Meaning**
>    O Sati, getting free from the curse of Sridama after hundred years today you unite with Shri Krishna happily.

That night Shri Krishna after taking permission from His father goes to meet Radharani, mother Yasoda, Nanda *baba* and other relatives:

> *ityuktā bhagavānkṛṣṇaḥ pitroranumatenaca
>
>   jagāma rādhikāsthānaṃ nandaśca gokulam tathā* [BVP - 4.126.7]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Thus saying Lord Krishna took the permission from His father and went to the place of Radha, Nanda and where the people of Gokula were.

So Shri Krishna actually met Radharani again after the hundred years of separation was over.

Answer (score 4):

**Lord Krishna actually returned to Vrindavan**.

Bhagavata Purana 1.11.9 says:

> yarhy ambujākṣāpasasāra bho bhavān  kurūn **madhūn** vātha suhṛd-didṛkṣayā
>   tatrābda-koṭi-pratimaḥ kṣaṇo bhaved  raviṁ vinākṣṇor iva nas tavācyuta
>
> O lotus-eyed Lord! When you go to Hastinapura or **Vraja** to see your
>   friends, one moment becomes like a trillion years for us, who belong
>   to you, and who become like eyes without the sun.

Sridhara Svami says :

> madhun here is Mathura.

At that time it is clear that his friends lived
only in Vraja, within Mathura area. All the people of Mathura had been transferred to Dvaraka.(SB 10.50.57). Therefore, here Mathura refers to Vraja within Mathura area.

Vishwanath Chakravarthy Thakur comments as follows:

> O lotus–eyed Lord! A version which has no bhavan is not accepted.
>   Kurun means Hastinapura and madhun means Vraja, not Mathura, because
>   at that time none of his friends resided there. This is understood
>   from the word “all” in the statement tatra yoga-prabhavena nitva
>   sarva-janam harih: the Lord by his power of yoga brought all the
>   inhabitants of Mathura to Dvaraka. (SB 10.50.57) He sent messengers
>   back to the gopis when he was leaving, saying “I will come back.” (SB
>   10.39.35) And he sent Nanda back to Vraja saying, “I will come to see you.” (SB 10.45.23) Though it is clearly mentioned in Padma Purana and
>   other Puranas that he did return, it can be understood from this verse
>   of Bhagavatam as well. When you leave, a moment becomes like a
>   trillion years for us (nah) who belong to you (tava).

[Saratha Darshini](https://www.amazon.in/%C5%9Ar%C4%ABmad-Bh%C4%81gavatam-First-Canto-S%C4%81r%C4%81rtha-dar%C5%9Bin%C4%AB-ebook/dp/B07DHJZMM8/ref=pd_sbs_351_12?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07DHJZMM8&pd_rd_r=740ebee2-90c6-4619-bd01-6d7eb6d82114&pd_rd_w=7AolF&pd_rd_wg=Z0cF9&pf_rd_p=b5c4df7b-dc8c-47a6-947a-01271326b67b&pf_rd_r=GR2VF7QGAYDHJFWKKV09&psc=1&refRID=GR2VF7QGAYDHJFWKKV09): Commentary of Vishwanath Chakravarthy translated by HH Bhanu Swami

[Padma Purana(6.252.19-28)](https://archive.org/details/PadmaPuranaMotilalVol.3Thru10/page/n2429) says that Lord Krishna returned to Vrindavana after killing Salva and Dantavakra.

> Having heard that Sisupala was killed, Dantavaktra came to Mathura to
>   fight with Krsria. Krsna, having learnt about it, got into his
>   chariot, and came to Mathura. On the bank of Yamuna, at the gate of
>   Mathura, a fight lasting a day and night took place between
>   Dantavaktra and Krsna; and Krsna killed him with (his) mace. He with
>   his entire body smashed dropped dead on the ground like a mountain
>   broken through with the thunderbolt. He too obtained the eternal,
>   highest position, the absorption into Visnu, obtainable by the
>   meditating saints. Thus Jaya and Vijaya, under the pretext of the
>   curse of Sanaka and others, descended into the mundane existence
>   merely for the sport of the lord, and in the three existences they
>   were killed by him alone. They obtained liberation at the end of three
>   existences. Krsna also, having killed him (i.e. Sisupala), having
>   crossed Yamuna, having gone to Nanda-vraja, having saluted his old
>   parents, and having consoled them and embraced by them with their
>   throats (choked) with tears, having embraced all old cowherds, having
>   cheered them up with gems, ornaments, etc. gratified the residents
>   there. On the charming sandy bank of Yamuna, covered with auspicious
>   trees. Krsna incessantly sported with the cowherdesses. Visnu, dressed
>   as a cowherd, lived here for a couple of months with (i.e. enjoying)
>   pleasure of charming sport and steady love.

There are many other indications in Bhagavata Purana which point to Krishna's returning to Vrindavan.

Answer (score 3):

### Garga Samhita says that Krishna went back to his childhood places where he was brought up, after killing Kansa in Mathura. He met his parents, Radha, friends, gopis etc.

---

**After leaving Vrindavan for killing Kansa in Mathura, why didn't Krishna ever go back to Vrindavan again?**

Krishna went back to Vrindavan after killing Kansa in Mathura.

> Listening to the words of His devotee, and remembering His own
>   promise, Lord Krishna, the infallible Supreme Personality of Godhead,
>   who loves His devotees, made up His mind to go to Vraja.
>
> Entrusting all His duties to Balarama, and mounting a chariot rich
>   with tinkling golden ornaments and yoked to eager horses, Krishna went
>   with Uddhava to Nanda's Gokula to meet His devotees.
>
> Seeing Govardhana and Gokula as He went, Krishna came to the Yamuna's
>   beautiful shore by Vrindavana forest.
>
> [[1-3, Chapter 19:The Festival on Shri Krishna Return, Canto 5, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_5.19:_The_Festival_on_Shri_Krishna_Return)

**Why didn't he ever meet Sri Radha again?**

Krishna met Sri Radha again after killing Kansa

> Shri Bahulashva said: What did the Supreme Lord do in the circle of
>   Vraja? How did He meet with Radha and the gopis?
>
> The Lord fulfilled the gopis' desires and then returned to Mathura.
>   You are the best of the wise. O king of the brahmanas, please tell me
>   this.
>
> Shri Narada said: Called there by Radha, Shri Krishna, the Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead, went at sunset to a secluded and always
>   pleasantly cool banana-tree forest.
>
> .......
>
> Radha would many times have burned that forest to ashes with the
>   flames of Her distress in Lord Krishna's absence. It was only the hope
>   that She would again meet Krishna that prevented Her.
>
> Then a hundred groups of gopis came there and informed Her that
>   Krishna had come.
>
> Shri Radha, the daughter of King Vrishabhanu, stood up at once.
>   Accompanied by Her friends, She went to meet Krishna.
>
> Speaking sweet and reverential words, sublimely beautiful Radha gave
>   Him a seat and offered Him padya, arghya, and many kinds of beautiful
>   offerings.
>
> Gazing at Lord Krishna, who eclipses the charms of many millions of
>   youthful Kamadevas, Radha became free of all distress. She was like a
>   yogi who, at last understanding the nature of the Supreme Personality
>   of Godhead, becomes free from the influence of the the material modes
>   of nature.
>
> [[Chapter 20: The Liberation of Ribhu Muni During the Rasa-dance Festival, Canto 5, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_5.20:_The_Liberation_of_Ribhu_Muni_During_the_Rasa-dance_Festival)

All the incidents I quoted above happened after [killing of Kansa](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_5.20:_The_Liberation_of_Ribhu_Muni_During_the_Rasa-dance_Festival) in Mathura.

Answer (score 2):

Lord Krishnas message in Bhagvadgeeta is to be practical and not emotional. So Lord himself has set the example for us to follow. He wants us to follow KARMAYOGA.
As far as Radha is concerned, it is a myth. Radha came into existance only after Gaudiya bhakti sampraday came into existance. Original scriptures of Krishnacharitra like Srimadbhagvat, Mahabharat or Harivansh do not mention any gopi called Radha in Krishnas life.All these are written by Maharshi Vyas who is the only authority to tell you about the life of Lord Krishna.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources.

Comment: can you direct us to sources please.

Comment: There is a difference between emotional and devotional.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Radha can not be a myth and the explanation you have in above answer is vague. If A is not B that does not mean its always C/D/E.  My other points would attempt to throw some light on this.

(2) This site page if you read goes closer to explain the reasons why Krishna never returned back to his childhood place. - http://www.purebhakti.com/teachers/bhakti-discourses-mainmenu-61/19-discourses-2000/205-why-did-krishna-not-return.html

(3) Also Krishna did mention all paths that lead to the one Brahma above all. He did not only explain the Karma but many other paths. Our lives are mix of each and every of those (Gyan, Bhakti and Karma, Dhyan) – Its like high-school, we study all subjects.. its only after maturing enough to pick a major/minor – is you will be on one path. Again the Goal is to reach him – no path is destination.

(4) In above other answers, there are quotes from Puranas which are also written by Lord Vyasa as crux & essence of Vedas/Upanishads but his Son - Lord Shukdev (Shuka) was the most close narrator for our age/yug. Now it is believed that Shukdev was born Sanyasi and had learned all vedas/Gita/Puranas while he was in his mother (Pinjala)'s womb and his Father was Lord Vyasa Himself. He never worn a piece of cloth, etc..

(5) There is one thing with authenticity of these three yug old scriptures. The Bhagavat Purana we have in our age/yug is more popularly narrated by Lord Shukdev told to King Parikshit who was almost the last king of Dwapar and kinda first king of Kaliyug's pre-production phase, if you will.

(6) Raadha is the extreme and perfect pure depiction of love and everytime Lord Shukdev would narrate Raadha, he would get "samadhi" for months..this is truly said for many other Lords and in my knowledge, some modern age devotees observed brief period of trance with Singing/Feeling for Raadha too Deepely.  Now King Parikshit had only 7 days before he would die of the Curse.. So Lord Shukdev only narrated the overviews of different paths and the ultimate truth of "Tattvabodh". He did not mention the "Bhakti" path too deeply.

**** ~~ This is a view of what I understood from various sources including life experiences, & there may be better explanation/justification out there. ****