# What are the instances where Krishna promised that he would return to Vrindavan?

Tags: puranas, krishna, vrindavana

What are the instances where Krishna promised that he would return to Vrindavan either himself or through representatives like Uddhava?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few instances when such promise was made.

First one when Krishna was leaving for Mathura:

> tās tathā tapyatīr vīkṣya sva-prasthāne yadūttamaḥ | sāntvayām āsa
>   sa-premair āyāsya iti dautyakaiḥ ||
>
> As he departed, that best of the Yadus saw how the gopīs, were
>   lamenting, and thus he consoled them by sending a messenger with this
>   loving promise: **“I will return.”** [SB 10.39.35](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/39/35/)

Another instance, Krishna speaks to his father Nanda. This occurs some days after Krishna kills Kamsa.

> yāta yūyaṁ vrajaṁ tāta vayaṁ ca sneha-duḥkhitān | jñātīn vo draṣṭum
>   eṣyāmo vidhāya suhṛdāṁ sukham ||
>
> Now you should all return to Vraja, dear father. **We shall come to see
>   you, our dear relatives who suffer in separation from us,** as soon as
>   we have given some happiness to your well-wishing friends. [SB 10.45.23](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/45/23/)

Another instance, Uddhava brings Krishna's message to the residents of Vrindavan.

> hatvā kaṁsaṁ raṅga-madhye pratīpaṁ sarva-sātvatām | yad āha vaḥ
>   samāgatya kṛṣṇaḥ satyaṁ karoti tat || āgamiṣyaty adīrgheṇa kālena
>   vrajam acyutaḥ | priyaṁ vidhāsyate pitror bhagavān sātvatāṁ patiḥ ||
>
> Having killed Kaṁsa, the enemy of all the Yadus, in the wrestling
>   arena, **Kṛṣṇa will now surely fulfill his promise to you by coming
>   back.** [SB 10.46.35](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/46/35/) 
>   Infallible Kṛṣṇa, the Lord of the devotees, **will
>   soon return to Vraja to satisfy His parents.** [SB 10.46.34](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/46/34/)

Comment: So, Did he actually returned?

Comment: @V.Aggarwal yes he did after killing Dantavakra check these: [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35861/17931) and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/30422/17931)

Answer (score 5):

Krishna promised such thing when he left for Mathura with Akrūra:

> गोप्यश्च दयितं कृष्णमनुव्रज्यानुरञ्जिता: ।
>
> प्रत्यादेशं भगवत: काङ्‌क्षन्त्यश्चावतस्थिरे ॥ ३४ ॥
>
> तास्तथा तप्यतीर्वीक्ष्य स्वप्रस्थाने यदूत्तम: ।
>
> सान्त्वयामास **सप्रेमैरायास्य इति** दौत्यकै: ॥ ३५ ॥
>
> [With His glances] Lord Kṛṣṇa somewhat pacified the gopīs, and they also followed behind for some time. Then, hoping He would give them some instruction, they stood still.
>
> As He departed, that best of the Yadus saw how the gopīs were lamenting, and thus He consoled them by sending a messenger with this **loving promise: “I will return.”**
>
> ~ [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa): Skandha 10: Chapter 39](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/39/)