# Why Lord Krishna didn't marry any of the Gopies?

Tags: krishna

As per my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7842/lesser-known-but-main-wives-of-lord-krishna-apart-from-rukmini-satyabhama-and-j), it is clear that Lord Krishna has many wives and he has not taken 'Ekapatni vrata' like Lord Rama. My question is regarding the girls of Vrindavan and friends of Radha, who were also in love with Lord Krishna. I know of one major one, ie, Lalita, but there were several others too.

I understand why Lord Krishna don't marry Radha because of a curse as described in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/393/1018), but my question is why couldn't he not marry the other ones. I remember that he was such a favourite among all gopies that they all prayed to Goddess Parvati for getting him as their husband, this incident later caused the Maha-raas where Lord Krishna manifested himself into multiple bodies to be with each of the Gopies. But that was only for that particular incident. In the later part of his life he married various other women some of whom, he just married because the women prayed/wished to marry him. Lord Krishna's figure is such that he grants everyone what he/she wants if he/she is dedicated to him. So, why he hasn't considered Gopies for marriage. Is there some other story/curse like Radha in case of Gopies.

Comment: Well, if you ask a Sri Vaishnava, they would say that Krishna did marry one of the Gopis, namely Nappinnai, daughter of Yashoda's brother Kumbagan: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7800/36

Comment: @Aby - What you mean that Lord Krishna was not committed one woman? I understand what you are trying to say, but it would be better if you dont choose loose words like "not commited" etc. Lord Krishna was completef committed to all his wives. There is hardly any instance any of his wives complained. Infact, they were all very very happy with Krishna as per puranas.

Comment: @Aby - Lord Krishna didnt marry the gopies, because instead of worshipping Lord Krishna who present in person among them they were interested in worshipping demi goddesses like Parvati. Infact, Lord Krishna taught gopies a lesson also, by doing so.

Comment: @Krishna I think Aby just meant committed as in promised, not committed as in devoted, i.e. Krishna didn't take an ekapatni vrata.  In any case, do you have any sources for Krishna punishing the Gopis for worshipping Parvati?  I remember the Srimad Bhagavatam mentioning the Gopis worshipping Parvati or some other goddess, but that was in order to obtain Krishna as their lover.

Comment: @Krishna, Keshav is right. By not committed I meant that Lord Krishna has not promised to be married to one woman only. Sorry, if I hurt anybody's religious sentiments, I will change the words in my question. Also, regarding the punishment story, I think I remember Arjuna also prayed to Goddess Durga during/before the Mahabharata battle, Arjuna doing the penance of Lord Shiva, Lord Krishna praying to Lord Shiva for getting a son, etc. So, I don't think there is any punishment thing happening here.

Comment: @Aby - Arjuna worshipping Durga? Which Mahabharata are you referring to? Also, Krishna worshipping Siva for child has cannot be an analogy for gopis worshipping godess parvati? You are comparing apples with oranges

Comment: @Aby- But, Gopis never got Krishna as Husband officially right. That is the what i call failure of the prayer to Goddess Katyayani.

Comment: @Krishna Arjuna prays to Durga right before the battle begins: http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06023.htm Durga appears before him and tells him that he is invincible since he has Narayana on his side.

Comment: @Krishna, the examples i gave were just to clarify that there were several other instances also when people pray to other Gods and they were not punished for that. Infact, I don't think that praying just another God should be a reason for punishment. I thought it was Goddess Parvati whom gopies prayed but as per your comment you said it was Goddess Katyayani. I am not sure about that. But if the goddess was Devi Parvati then she should be treated equal/near equal as Lord Shiva and thus there shouldn't be any punishment thing at all.

Comment: @Krishna, also there was no full failure of prayers also, as gopies got Lord Krishna for the night of Maha-Raas. Again I am not sure whether they prayed to get Lord Krishna as husband or lover. But the point is why only for one night when He could have married them for life.

Comment: @Krishna This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26299/discussion-on-question-by-aby-why-lord-krishna-didnt-marry-any-of-the-gopies).

Answer (score 2):

If you know Brmha Vimohan leela where Lord Bramha doubts krishna and steel all cows and gopa friends for the time that corresponded to one year according to earthly planet to check whether Krishna is supreme Lord or not. Krishna expanded himself as many as cows and gopas were there and when Bramha ji comes he is bewildered to see the cows and gopas which he stole later he comes to an understanding that Krishna is supreme of all gods even Lord Vishnu. 
It happened during this period of one year that all gopas got married so in one sense it was Krishna who got married to all gopis of Braj. 
reason why Rasa dance is spiritually topmost thing and why Krishna is not so much in physical association of gopis :1. Krishna is known as RasaRaja enjoyer of all mellows so spiritually what is topmost materially that is most perverted thing. Gopis dancing with Krishna represents their topmost surrender as a devotees that how one should leave everything and just surrender to Supreme... However such thing in material circle is most perverted thing. 
2. Gopis were in their spiritual bodies.
3. Rasa leela is glorified by many sages
4. gopis of brajbhumi were experiencing highest form of love in seperation.
Moreover marriage is not a physical affair in Spiritual circle it means dedication of one body mind and soul so in that sense any devotee is married to Krishna.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: @Einstein'sLover, thanks for your answer but if I understand correctly then the marriage of ALL Gopies who loved Lord Krishna happened during that one year when Lord Bramha steel all Gopas? I think the incident of stealing cows and Gopas happened when Lord Krishna was in Gokul and when He was leaving for Mathura, Radha Ji and all Gopies were trying to stop Him. I don't think these gopies are the ones married to gopas (Lord Krishna's expansion).

Comment: Also, if gopies married Gopas who were Lord Krishna's expansion. Now when Lord Bramha returned back the original gopas, what would have happened. Were the gopies living with the original gopas who were not the ones who they married (as they married Lord Krishna in form of Gopa) for the rest of their lives. This will then become unethical. I think gopies loved Lord Krishna but they later married someone else.

Comment: The details of this story comes in padma puran. As explained earlier gopas gopis everyone in braja is wife of Krishna as by definition they love Krishna and they are always submissive to Krishna. So gopis were wife of Lord since eternity however their are certain leelas that Lord depicts to increase his mellow s with his devotees. During this one year time Krishna wanted to reciprocate with each and every mother including cows who were desiring to have him as their son. So unethical only if you look it from material point of view Krishna s point of view is the view that matters brajvasis.